# Registration failed on freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I've got a registration problem in my local freeswitch.
I've installed in a WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 and freeswitch 1.10.3
When I'm trying to register my user (3333) with a SIP client (ex. Microsip) but

- if I use the local IP address I receive an error like You must define a domain called '192.168.1.34' in your directory and add a user with the id="3333" attribute
- if I use the external IP I receive a "service unvailable"

I've created a 3333 xml file under conf/directory/default folder.

What I have to do in order to register my user?

Here's my config.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain should be FreeSwitch IP, eg, 188.xxx....

Comment: Domain in xml or in client configuration?

Comment: client configuration, make sure client send out Register with From/To Header in xxx@188.xxx format